# "Fake out" a P4 merge

Tags: merge, branch, perforce, branching-and-merging, perforce-integrate

Is it possible to execute a "fake merge" between P4 branches? In short, we have a script that checks for un-merged changes between branches, and auto-emails team members every day to let them know if they've failed to merge changes from one branch to another. However, there are cases where it would be a bad idea to execute such merges (i.e. dependency lists that are branch-specific, for example), and we'd like to appease the nag-bot by having it detect "all changes in `A` since yesterday have been merged into `B`".

Is there a way to effectively (i.e. via the CLI):

- Execute a `p4 integ` and `p4 resolve` operation so that it appears branch "A" has been merged into branch "B"....
- But effectively execute a `p4 revert` operation on branch "B" so that just the tracking information is committed, and none of the actual code is merged into branch "B"?

In short, it would be a "merge but accept-full-theirs and discard yours even if no conflicts" operation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's `p4 resolve -ay`.

```
p4 integ A/... B/...
p4 resolve -ay
p4 submit -d "B is ignoring changes from A."
```

You will still need to submit the new revision (because merge records are themselves versioned information and need to be associated with a submit), but the revision will have no diffs from the previous revision and exists solely to represent that B has "ignored" that change from A.

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize the `-ay` flag ignored non-conflicting changes.

Comment: The `-ay` flag accepts the file in your workspace ("yours") without any changes at all (opposite of `-at` which accepts an exact copy of the source file from the depot).